# Which port is used for Screen Capture from device

Tags: android, adb, screen-capture

I am using Android Studio for development.
I have a remote Android-powered device which I access using ADB over TCPIP. This device has a firewall so I need to enable specific ports for my need during development. I have enabled port 5555 so that ADB is able to connect there, but I don't find information which port is the Screen Capture using. At the moment when I press the button in Android Studio to get Screen Capture from the device, it opens a progress bar and never stops "loading".
I stop it by disconnecting ADB from command line.

I cannot connect over USB to this device so I don't know if it has even a restriction for providing capture (I read there is such restriction for some phones).

Comment: I would expect it tunnels through ADB's existing connection.

Comment: If that's the case, then there is probably some restriction on the device side, or an ADB problem on one of the two sides...